# OpenAPI Spec Connection Refused

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, openapi

I am having problem with my OpenAPI spec file. I am trying to call an exposed url to 'GET' an id but every time i port forward the service to my local and then try to send request through API document my connection is refused. I would appreciate any help. The id that i am expecting would be in JSON format. Below is my spec file

```
openapi: "3.0.0"
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Id Generator
servers:
   url: www.someurl.com
paths:
  /posts:
    get:
      summary: Get Id
      operationId: id
      tags:
        - posts
      responses:
        200:
          description: successful operation
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
              $ref: "#/definition/Post"
        default:
          description: unexpected error
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
              $ref: "#/definition/Error"

definition:
    Post:
    type: object 
    properties:
        id:
          type: string
    Error:
      properties:
        id:
          type: string
```

Comment: How are you making the API calls - from Swagger UI in a browser or somehow else?

Comment: Your spec is not a valid 3.0.0 or 2.0 spec, by the way. The indentation is wrong in several places, and the spec uses a mix of 2.0 and 3.0.0 keywords which is wrong.

Comment: @Helen i am making API calls using swagger UI. I am not getting indentation error on visual studio code.

Comment: @Helen i have made some corrections to alleviate the mixing of 2.0 and 3.0. I have re-posted my spec above. There might be indentation issue since i am pasting it here directly. But i don't get any indentation error on visual studio code. I am still unable to successfully get response using my spec file.

Comment: I am new to openapi and I would like to ask how did you get the openapi yaml file? Is it generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of June 21 2017, OpenAPI Specification 3.0 is not out yet and Swagger UI does not support OpenAPI 3.0 yet, so your example can't possibly work. Keep an eye on [Swagger UI releases](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/releases) page to know when support for OpenAPI 3.0 is available.

Also, you'll need to fix the errors in your spec to make it a valid OpenAPI 3.0 spec:

- `servers` is an array, so change that to:

  ```
  servers:
    - url: http://www.someurl.com
  ```
- Response status codes must be quoted: `"200"` or `'200'`.
- Indent the `$ref` under schemas:

  ```
                schema:
                  $ref: "#/definition/Post"
                ...
                schema:
                  $ref: "#/definition/Error"
  ```
- Change `definition` to `components`->`schemas` and fix the indentation for `Post`:

  ```
  components:
    schemas:
      Post:
        type: object 
        properties:
          id:
            type: string
      Error:
        properties:
          id:
            type: string
  ```